# Javascript to get amount from radio button with input title

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a bit stuck here as I could find many sample codes here getting the value from radio input with id or value.

How do I get it from a title as below using only pure javascript and then output to total ?

```
<p>
    Home address - &pound;4.99 <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="home" title="4.99" checked = "checked" />&nbsp; | &nbsp;
    Collect from warehouse - no charge <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="trade" title="0" />
</p>

<section id="checkCost">
    <h2>Total cost</h2>
    Total <input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="10" readonly="readonly" />
</section>
```

JS:

```
var checkedRadioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
```

Comment: What is your browser ?

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: are you expecting this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/z75d0q3L ?

Comment: Why are you putting the amount in the `title` attribute instead of `value`? Isn't that what the value is for?

Answer (score 0):

you can use getAttribute function

```
var checkedRadioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');

var total = 0;
for ( var i = 0 ;  i < checkedRadioButtons.length ; i++ ) {   
    total += Number( checkedRadioButtons[i].getAttribute('title') );
}

console.log( total );
```

Comment: Sorry may I ask why use console.log ?

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to place it within function isChecked() but somehow it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Use `getAttribute` to get the `title` attribute value.

```js
var checkedRadioButtons = document.querySelector('[name="deliveryType"]:checked');

document.getElementById("total").value = checkedRadioButtons.getAttribute("title");
```

```html
<p>Home address - &pound;4.99
    <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="home" title="4.99" checked="checked" />&nbsp; | &nbsp; Collect from warehouse - no charge
    <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="trade" title="0" />
</p>
<section id="checkCost">
    
<h2>Total cost</h2>
Total
    <input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="10" readonly="readonly" />
</section>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/z75d0q3L

Comment: Why not use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`, since there can only be one checked radio button in a group? then you don't need the `[0]` index.

Comment: @KishoreSahas thanks, i was testing the jsfiddle & snippet but it doesn't go back to zero when I select the "no charge". Can I also use with function isChecked() ?

Comment: @DoranL it was not mentioned in the question, please http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/z75d0q3L/3